# What is the npm tmp directory? Can I delete it?

Tags: node.js, git, ubuntu, npm

On a brand new Ubuntu machine 12.04.3 I did the following installations on my home directory:

- Git: `sudo apt-get install git`
- Node.js: `sudo apt-get install nodejs` and updated it [with](http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs) `sudo npm cache clean -f`, `sudo npm install -g n`, `sudo n stable`
- npm: `sudo apt-get install npm` and then updated it with `npm update npm -g`
- Yoeman: `sudo npm install -g yo`

A new "tmp" directory popped up in my home directory with the following structure:

```
npm-13728-uErqEQ4O:
1392566713336-0.9297236264683306  1392566726706-0.4921755278483033

npm-13763-yoMEDYdC:
1392566864990-0.09957328205928206
```

Each of the uErqEQ4O subdirectories contain:

```
tmp.tgz

package:
AUTHORS  configure        html     make.bat  node_modules  scripts
bin      CONTRIBUTING.md  lib      Makefile  package.json  test
cli.js   doc              LICENSE  man       README.md
```

The yoMEDYdC subdirectory contains:

```
tmp.tgz

package:
cli.js  package.json  readme.md  scripts  yeoman.txt  yoyo.js
```

**What is this tmp npm directory** and everything inside it? Why was it generated?

**Can I delete it?** If not, where can I move it to because I don't want it in my home directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tmp or temp** generally means some kind of temporary storage, which is auto generated by program (mostly per one session):

Here is what the npm tmp directory is:

> Temporary files are stored by default in the folder specified by the
>   tmp config, which defaults to the TMPDIR, TMP, or TEMP environment
>   variables, or /tmp on Unix and c:\windows\temp on Windows.
>
> Temp files are given a unique folder under this root for each run of
>   the program, and are deleted upon successful exit.

If you are not sure can you delete it, just add some prefix to it e.g. **_tmp** and try to run you app. If it runs with prefix then you can delete it. If not, then you app has some kind of reference to it.

Comment: Thanks! How come it's not deleted though?